# ibm 1 sql creating - need to add 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have following view which is working but not sure how to add 2 tables to join.

This table is `adres1` and it will join on the `IDENT#` and `IDSFX#` to table
`prodta.adres1` called `adent#` and `adsfx#`, there I need a col. `ads15`. 
then i also need to get the `ship to`, row in this `adres1`. this we get first from the `order` table, `prodta`. `oeord1` in col. `odgrc#`. This `grc#` is 11 pos and is combined 8 and 3 of the `ent` and `suf`. these 2 represent the `ship to` record and looking in same table `adres1` (we do have many logical views on them if it's easier, like `adres15`) we can get `col. ADSTTC`  for the ship to state.

Not sure if can included these 2 new parts to the current view created code below. Please ask if something not clear, it's an old system and somewhat developed convoluted.

```
CREATE VIEW Prolib.SHPWEIGHTP AS SELECT 
 T01.IDORD#, 
 T01.IDDOCD, 
 T01.IDPRT#, 
 t01.idsfx#, 
 T01.IDSHP#, 
 T01.IDNTU$, 
 T01.IDENT#, 
 (T01.IDNTU$ * T01.IDSHP#) AS LINTOT,
 T02.IAPTWT, 
 T02.IARCC3,             
 T02.IAPRLC, 
 T03.PHVIAC, 
 T03.PHORD#,
 PHSFX#,
 T01.IDORDT,                    
 T01.IDHCD3 
FROM PRODTA.OEINDLID T01 
INNER JOIN PRODTA.ICPRTMIA T02 ON T01.IDPRT# = T02.IAPRT# 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
    PHORD#,
    PHSFX#, 
    PHVIAC, 
    PHWGHT 
  FROM proccdta.pshippf) AS T03 ON t01.idord# = T03.phord# 
WHERE T01.IDHCD3 IN ('MDL','TRP')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking, and it looks like some of the column-names are missing from your description, but this should get you pretty close:

```
CREATE VIEW Prolib.SHPWEIGHTP AS 
  SELECT T01.IDORD#, 
         T01.IDDOCD,
         T01.IDPRT#, 
         t01.idsfx#, 
         T01.IDSHP#, 
         T01.IDNTU$, 
         T01.IDENT#, 
         ( T01.IDNTU$ * T01.IDSHP# ) AS LINTOT , 
         T02.IAPTWT, 
         T02.IARCC3,
         T02.IAPRLC, 
         T03.PHVIAC, 
         T03.PHORD#,PHSFX#,
         T01.IDORDT,
         T01.IDHCD3,
         t04.ads15
    FROM PRODTA.OEINDLID T01
   INNER JOIN PRODTA.ICPRTMIA T02
      ON T01.IDPRT# = T02.IAPRT#
   INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                      PHORD#,
                      PHSFX#, 
                      PHVIAC, 
                      PHWGHT
                 FROM proccdta.pshippf) AS T03
      ON t01.idord# = T03.phord#
    JOIN prodta.adres1 as t04
      on t04.adent# = t01.adent#
     and t04.adsfx# = t01.adsfx#
    JOIN prodta.oeord1 t05
      on t05.odgrc# = T01.IDENT# || T01.SUFFIX
   WHERE T01.IDHCD3 IN ('MDL','TRP')
```

Let me know if you need more details.

HTH !